# white background for few seconds before splash screen android

Tags: android, themes

I facing a problem while launching the app. A white background is displayed for a few seconds at first start up, then at second start up sometime it doesn't appears.

I used this in my AppTheme

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_app_background</item>
```

I am successful but it shows the `my_app_background` image inside the app also instead of `white background`

My current AppTheme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    </style>
```

Splash Screen

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity{

    // Splash screen timer
    public static int SCREEN_TIMEOUT=3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

                Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this,"Message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, SCREEN_TIMEOUT);

    }
}
```

Comment: Will you please paste the code for your Splash Activity ?

Answer (score 0):

put this in your manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

** put this line in your style it prevents opening white screen before splash