# Android Flash screen loading white screen

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have following code in my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    ImageView my_flash_screen;
    DB db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        my_flash_screen= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_flash_screen);



        MainTask task = new MainTask();
        task.execute();

       AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
        animation.addAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(0.0F, 1.0F));
        animation.addAnimation(new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1, 0.0f, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f)); // Change args as desired
        animation.setDuration(1500);

        my_flash_screen.startAnimation(animation);

        new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            public void onFinish() {


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NavigationActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }.start();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private class MainTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            if(FontUtil.storeSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).getString("font", "").isEmpty())
            {
                FontUtil.savePrefs("font", "SKN.TTF",getApplicationContext());
                FontUtil.savesize("fb",22, getApplicationContext());

                Log.d("Test","insidefont");
            }

            try {
                if(db==null){
                    db=new DB(getApplicationContext());
                    db.createdatabase();
                    Log.d("Test","intialise first");
                }
                Log.d("Test","intialise second");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mynew"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mynew"

        android:id="@+id/my_flash_screen"
        android:contentDescription="loading image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Some times when i open my app only white screen will showing.i have used AsyncTask to copy database from asset folder to device and shared preference will set font type and size.Can any one help me to fix the issue.Thank You.

Before asking question i have read following questions

[White background when Android app start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738879/white-background-when-android-app-start-up)

[white background for few seconds before splash screen android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907475/white-background-for-few-seconds-before-splash-screen-android)

[Splash screen activity background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155028/splash-screen-activity-background-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes happened due to it doesn't recognise your image immediately.It took some time. Till that time it show white screen.

I'll give you idea how you can use and avoid this problem.

Put your image to style and use it as theme.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorText</item>
</style>

<!--SplashActivity theme.-->

<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/ic_splash</item>
</style>
```

and use your xml simply blank

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Then just use that theme in your splash activity.

```
<activity
        android:name=".module.splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

**Second Option :**

My first way is perfect but you want to use some animation or something else then you this style and use same layout which you set image in your layout.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/kitean_primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/kitean_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/kitean_color_accent</item>
</style>
```

This is the best way to avoid this problem. Thanks

Comment: @Saveen.Thanks .i will try

Comment: @Saveen.how to release memory when fragment changes

Comment: .i am using two background befroe loading image through  animation .as you can see xml

Comment: it help you for release memory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241433/fragments-are-not-being-released-from-memory

Comment: but i will change later i mean i am using different images

Comment: yes i have updated my answer hope this will help you.

Comment: @Saveen.now white screen wont come but it will struct in that image only .not opening new activity

Comment: Out of memory on a 8294416-byte allocation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127005/discussion-between-saveen-and-icoders).